# creating shovels through spring xml

Tags: spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-shovel

Using spring XML, just like we create queues, binding etc as below

```
<rabbit:queue name="TestQueue" />
<rabbit:topic-exchange name="TestExchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="TestQueue" pattern="Test.Key" />
  </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>
```

Can we also create shovels?

Please let me know. i want to create dynamic shovels automatically. Not manually through management plugin.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we also create shovels?

No; Spring-AMQP provisioning is limited to what you can do over the AMQP protocol (exchanges, queues, bindings).

RabbitMQ provides a REST API which can be used for other provisioning.

They provide a [Java binding for the API](https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop).